# How to do recursive calculation in SPSS Modeler

Tags: spss-modeler

If I want to compute a value that relies on the previous one (Recursive functions) how can I do it in SPSS ? Example:

```
Q0 = 0 
Qn = Q(n-1) + Constant
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many research I couldn't find any way to do recursive function with SPSS Modeler. The only work around is to use `R Transform` node within SPSS. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

If by "... the previous one ..." you mean the value of the same field (or a different field) for the previous record, you can use the [@OFFSET(FIELD, EXPR)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3RA7_17.0.0/clementine/clem_function_ref_sequence.html) function.
The function allows you to access values from records other than the current one based on a relative reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the `@OFFSET` function is not recursive. Let me give you an example: if `Q0 = 1`, Q1 does not exist yet. you'll calculate it by doing `Q1 = Q0/1 + C = C`. and then you'll do `Q2 = (Q1 + Q0)/2 + C` and so on. You can't do this at once because `@OFFSET` requires that all the values already exists. Try it one of those [link] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: OK - so "... previous one ..." refers to a value for a different field in the same record and you are looking to add a number if new fields to the data using this type of formula.
I cannot immediately think of an easy way to do that, but you could use scripting to create a series of Derive nodes with the formula to perform the recursive calculation and use an appropriate naming convention for the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to do, you can either chain many derive nodes or refer to the previous value in a column after sorting them.

Answer (score 0):

I started with creating a domain context for the stream data flow (iterations) with a simple csv source file with records keeping one field N (range from 1 to 100), just to limit the example. Then I connected this data source with a derive node that defines the variable field Q:

if not(@NULL(@OFFSET(N,1))) then @OFFSET(Q,1) + 2 else 0 endif

Here I used the value 2 for the Constant in the example above. I see this being a recursive function and it relies on the OFFSET just as Kenneth suggested above.